# Excel VBA If Cell in a column U is Blank, enter text "600SUB"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an exported txt file that i am running several macros on to create an import file.

In column U, if a cell is blank i need it to enter "600SUB"

Then i need to run the rest of the macros.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use SpecialCells to locate and fill truly blank cells.

```
with worksheets(1)
    on error resume next
    intersect(.usedrange, .range("U:U")).specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks) = "600SUB"
    on error goto 0
end with

'run rest of procedures
```

Comment: This is actually a really creative way to pick out blank cells, thanks for this