# Excel VBA - My Loop is Taking Forever - Ideas?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that is the result of copying the contents of a phone bill into excel.  I have written code to move the charges, which appear below the phone number, next to the phone number.  The problem is there are nearly 6,000 lines in a standard sheet to process.  I would like to know if there is a better way to move the data than what I have.
Thanks,

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For X = 2 To LastRow
    If Left(Range("A" & X).Value, 1) = "(" Or Left(Range("A" & X).Value, 1) = "C" Then
        Range("B" & X).Value = Range("A" & (X + 1)).Value
        Range("A" & (X + 1)).Delete
    End If
Next X
```

Basically it is looking at the cell based on the loop and if it fits then moving the contents below it to the cell next to it and getting rid of the resulting blank row.

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested, since you've provided no data to test with. This assumes there's only data in column A.

Iterating backwards, beginning at `LastRow - 1` (the last row shouldn't have a row of charges beneath it, by virtue of being the "last" row). Instead of `Delete`, I just `Clear`, and then use the `SpecialCells` method to delete all empty cells (rows) at the end of the loop.

I revised the logic to identify phone number cells based on the assumption that they either begin with a "C" (from your logic) or they're of format (XXX)-... I figure a phone number can be identified by this logic:

- First character = "("
- Fourth & Fifth characters = ")-"

Which should avoid the false positives since both phone numbers and credits begin with a "(".

```
Dim thisCell as Range
For X = LastRow - 1 to 2 Step - 1
    Set thisCell = Range("A1" & X)
    'If this cell is a phone number, modify if needed:
    If (Left(thisCell.Value, 1) = "(" And Mid(thisCell.Value,2,4) = ")-") _
       Or Left(thisCell.Value, 1) = "C" Then       
       ' Move what's below it [offset(1,0)] to the adjacent cell [offset(0, 1)]
        thisCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = thisCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
        ' Make the cell beneath empty
        thisCell.Offset(1, 0).Clear
    End If
Next X

' Delete the empty rows:
Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I applologize for not giving the data.  I was needed on another project and could not come back to this.  I didn't want people thinking I just left it for no reason.  I may be able to get back to this in the future and when I can I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete rows inside your loop. It causes many iterations of deletions. Instead, create a `Union` (collection) of cells as you loop. Then, once your loop is complete, delete the `Union` of cells all at once.

Also, looping through a range (`For Each`) in this case will be faster than a `For i` loop.

---

```
Sub DeleteMe()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("???")
Dim MyCell As Range, DeleteMe As Range, LRow As Long

LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each MyCell In ws.Range("A2:A" & LRow)
    If Left(MyCell, 1) = "(" Or Left(MyCell, 1) = "C" Then
        MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value = MyCell.Offset(1).Value
        If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = MyCell
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, MyCell)
        End If
    End If
Next MyCell

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637695/vba-deleting-rows-with-the-like-operator/52637747#52637747) solution from yesterday explaining the benefits of this method. The solution also shows you how to properly delete rows inside a loop.