# Removing Duplicates with Find and Delete is suddenly slow

Tags: excel, vba

I used to use a piece of a macro that someone here provided me as a means to remove duplicates from one column when they are found in another column. For some reason, the remove duplicates function never worked for me and reading on it said that it could be buggy. This was a means around that and it worked beautifully in another sheet. I am repurposing the code but when using it now, it is very slow with a small dataset to sort through (only 350 rows). It has no issue finding the duplicate but the issue arises when it uses .delete shift:=up. I do this so that there are not blank cells throughout the column but it now says about 3 seconds to complete each deletion and shift. If I simply use .clear, the reaction is immediate but this leaves me with blank cells throughout the column. Does anyone see a reason why this code would take so long to complete?

Column V is the comparison column and column M is the column I am removing duplicates from.

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
    Dim M As Range, V As Range
    Dim rc As Long
    rc = Rows.Count
    Set M = Range("M6:M" & Cells(rc, "M").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set V = Range("V6:V" & Cells(rc, "V").End(xlUp).Row)
    Mcnt = M.Count + 5

'Copies SAP Batch summary data into New Batch Summary
If Range("J6") = "" Then
Exit Sub
Else
Range("I6:J6", Range("I6:J6").End(xlDown)).Copy Range("L6:M6")
End If

'Moves From bottom of column M and goes up
    For i = Mcnt To 5 Step -1
        If V.Find(what:=Cells(i, "M"), after:=V(1)) Is Nothing Then
       Else
            'Cells(i, "M").Clear
            Cells(i, "M").Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i

'Positions data in the New Batch column
'Call Reposition_Data
End Sub
```

Comment: Calculations, events firing.  could be many reasons.  It would be better to build a union range and delete all at once.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52637747/6706419) solution can show you how to delete rows with a `Union` which can save a lot of memory. Your current code has many iterations of rows being deleted which is time consuming. Using a loop just has a single iteration of rows being deleted

Comment: Using a `Union` just has a single iteration of rows being deleted***.