# Using InStr or Left/Right to check variables within reverse loop

Tags: excel, vba

At work I have a repetitive task of going through a list of account activity and changes where I have to delete blank spaces and lines that are not necessary for the maintenance I perform. For 80% of the these I am able to work a for each loop that is pretty inelegant but effective.
Example:

```
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If InStr(1, c.Value, SubString7) = 1 Then   ' find earn lines and remove
c.EntireRow.Offset(1).Delete
c.EntireRow.Clear
c.EntireRow.Offset(-1).Delete
End If

Next
```

The substring is the descriptive title line for each type of transaction. The one I am having trouble with is variable, while the others are not. It can be 9 lines long or 6 lines long, and could also be positive or negative but each possibility comes with the same title line.
Based on everything I could find to try to figure it out, I need to use a loop, moving from bottom to top. I cannot get it to trigger with either InStr, nor left/right.

This is a cut down version of what I am trying now:

```
    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For rowcounter = lr To 0 Step -1
          If VBA.Strings.Left(Cells(rowcounter).Value, 11) Like "Earn Manual" Then
              If VBA.Strings.Left(Cells(rowcounter + 5).Value, 1) = "-" Then 
                  If VBA.Strings.Left(Cells(rowcounter + 6).Value, 3) = "AVG" Then 
                  Cells(rowcounter).EntireRow.Offset(5).Delete 'this, several more times with different offsets for the required lines
                  Else
                  Cells(rowcounter).EntireRow.Offset(5).Delete 'different ones, finalizing removals on the negative value items
                  End if
              Else
                  If VBA.Strings.Left(Cells(rowcounter + 6).Value, 3) = "AVG" Then
                  Cells(rowcounter).EntireRow.Offset(5).Delete 'again, but with different offsets
                  Else 'There is one line for these that I have to split into two lines, not sure if this will even work as I cannot get it to trigger
                  Cells(rowcounter).EntireRow.Offset(8).Delete
                  Cells(rowcounter).EntireRow.Offset(7).Delete
                  Cells(rowcounter + 4).Value = VBA.Strings.Right(Cells(rowcounter + 3).Value, 25)
                  Cells(rowcounter + 3).Value = VBA.Strings.Left(Cells(rowcounter + 3).Value, 13)
                  End if 
              End If
          End If

Next Rowcounter
```

I had originally had that first If line as:

```
If InStr(1, Cells(rowcounter).Value, SubString8) = 1 Then
```

I tried switching to `Left()` and Like but still no dice.

Attempting to provide sample of input/output

sample data:
[image: sample data]

Goal output from column A:

[Retained Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uEyM.png)

Update again, new and improved code that is still failing:

```
Next
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Range("A" & i) Like "Earn Manual*" Then
            If ws.c("A" & i + 5) Like "-*" Then
                If ws.c("A" & i + 6) Like "Avg*" Then
                    Set Deleteme = c.Range("A" & i, "A" & i + 8) ' shows AVG, negative value
                Else
                    Set Deleteme = c.Range("A" & i, "A" & i + 5) ' no AVG, negative value
                End If

            Else
                If ws.c("A" & i + 6) Like "Avg*" Then
                    Set Deleteme = c.Range("A" & i, "A" & i + 3)
                    Set Deleteme = c.Range("A" & i + 5)
                Else
                    Set Deleteme = c.Range("A" & i, "A" & i + 3)
                    Set Deleteme = c.Range("A" & i + 5)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Set Deleteme = Union(Deleteme, ws.Range("A" & i))
        End If
Next A
```

Comment: Hi Chris, When deleting it's best to start at the end and work your way backwards as you are. A few things here - you can use `LEFT` instead of `VBA.Strings.Left` which may make your code shorter. You want to be very careful when you're using offsets to delete because each row you delete will change the offsets. A better method would be `Resize` which will include all the lines you have - so if you wanted to delete 5-8 for example, you could use `Offset(5).Resize(3).EntireRow.Delete` This will select the 5 rows below, add 2 extra rows, and delete them as well.

Comment: When using the `Like` keyword, you can also include wildcards - so you can use `Like "*Earn Manual*"` and not worry about the `LEFT` at all - any string containing the word `Earn Manual` will be detected when you include the wildcards.

Comment: I can offer more help if you can include a small subset of your data as an input and the output you are looking for - that would help quite a bit.

Comment: My guess is that you're running into problems because you're not keeping the deletes in mind when you use your offsets (I can't tell for sure because I can't see your input/output). If you delete something 3 rows down, everything below that has now been shifted up. i'm sure you can see how it's possible for that to create issues.

Comment: You should includes a screen shot of muck data.  Saying 6 Rows is probably better than 6 lines

Comment: `Cells(rowcounter).EntireRow.Offset(5).Delete` is in both conditions for `If VBA.Strings.Left(Cells(rowcounter + 6).Value, 3) = "AVG" Then`. Is that a typo? If not, why even make the check?

Comment: @tinman I will try to do so, but I am not sure if I will be able to via my work computer.

Comment: @comintern If it is a negative value with AVG, i just need to clear lines. If it is a positive value AVG I need to do that left/right split to turn one line of data into two. The code is long and unwieldy so I was trying my best to summarize for brevity.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your actual code then?

Comment: @user1274820 I thought that was the point of running from the bottom to the top. I was under the impression that it wouldn't matter this way and would simply work relative to the current 'rowcounter' value at the time it triggered the 'if'. Will changes to the total rows hurt me in the middle of the if loop?

Comment: @Comintern New guy, didn't know I could do that.

Comment: NP - if it isn't relevant, you can also feel free to omit it entirely. That said, I'm guessing @user1274820 is correct about your deletes - one option would be to build a union of the rows you're *going to* delete, and just delete everything after you identify the delete targets.  That's much, much easier to keep track of.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637695/vba-deleting-rows-with-the-like-operator/52637747#52637747) is a solution using `Like` operator and deleting rows using a `Union` to avoid the issues that come along with non-backwards loop deleting

Comment: @urdearboy Thank you for the suggestion. I tried to implement this process, but am coming up with the same result. I can set a breakpoint and watch 'i' as it iterates down through the list, but it just looks at each line as before. It is far more streamlined with the advise I got, but still no luck. Is it that I cannot apply modifiers to i when designating cells? I have edited my question to show the code as implemented.

Comment: @ChrisW is "output without the code" what you WANT it to be? or is that wrong too?

Comment: @user1274820 I was tracking for myself that I get the same result both with the code included and without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way that I can get this 100% correct because it was based of the OP's new and improve code, which has some flaws in its logic.  My goal was to simply the overall syntax to make it easier to get right.

The problem with deletion with offset values is that the values move on you.  My solution is to Union all rows to be deleted and delete them then after the loop is done.  This is not only more efficient but it allows us to loop from top to bottom.  This makes the code it much easier to follow.

When Union ranges in this way, you must first test to see if the target range to be deleted is Nothing.  If the target range is Nothing, we Set it to the new range else we Union the two ranges. I wrote a subroutine `UnionRange()`, so that we would not have to repeat this process each time we needed to do a Union.

`With` blocks, `Range.Offset()` and `Range.Resize()` were used to simply the syntax.  I feel like this is cleaner than concatenating addresses inside of a range (e.g. Range("A" & i + 5) and Range("A" & i, "A" & i + 8)).

```
Sub CleanUp()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim r As Long
        Dim rUnion As Range
        For r = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            With .Cells(r, 1)
                If .Value = "" Then
                    UnionRange rUnion, .Offset(0)
                ElseIf .Value Like "Earn Manual*" Then
                    If .Offset(6).Value Like "Avg*" Then    ' shows AVG, negative value
                        UnionRange rUnion, .Offset(8)
                    Else                              ' no AVG, negative value
                        UnionRange rUnion, .Offset(5)
                    End If
                Else
                    'This can't be right
                    If .Offset(6).Value Like "Avg*" Then 'If Like "Avg*" Then Delete These Cells
                        UnionRange rUnion, .Resize(3)
                        UnionRange rUnion, .Offset(5)
                    Else 'Hell If Not Like "Avg*" Then Delete The Same Cells Anyway
                        UnionRange rUnion, .Resize(3)
                        UnionRange rUnion, .Offset(5)
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With

    If Not rUnion Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        rUnion.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub

Sub UnionRange(ByRef rUnion As Range, ByRef Cell As Range)
    If rUnion Is Nothing Then
        Set rUnion = Cell
    Else
        Set rUnion = Union(rUnion, Cell)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had always been approaching this from the headspace of keeping what I needed, rather than removing what I did not. I need to redo the majority of my code, but coming at it with this seems to be doing the trick. Thank you (all of you!) for your help.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  I'm glad that it helped.