# Delete hidden (filtered) rows in a table

Tags: excel, vba

how can I delete hidden (filtered) rows in a table?  I tried this. But i guess Excel does not recognize ".SpecialCells(xlCellTypeHidden)"

```
If ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeHidden).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/specialcells-xlcelltypehidden.946259/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that looping is slow and the below proposed looping solution did not work on a table. Again, my earlier question was "*How can I delete hidden (filtered) rows in a table? I tried this. But i guess Excel does not recognize ".SpecialCells(xlCellType**Hidden**)*".  So, instead I sort-of reversed the .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) logic by first coloring the filtered (visible rows) in the table yellow.  Then I filtered by color: No Fill.  Used .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) to delete those rows, remove the filter and removed the coloring on the rows that where visible to begin with.  Resulting in the hidden (filtered out) rows being deleted.  This sub routine deletes hidden rows very quickly.

```
Sub DeleteHiddenRows()
'Keep all visible rows and remove all other hidden rows in a table

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'colors visible rows yellow if visible
    If ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
    
    'reverse filter on non-colored filled cells
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    RGB(255, 255, 255), Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
    
     'if data is in a table run this to delete visible - non-colored cells
    If ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
     
    'remove cell color in table data body range
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
     
'Turn back on screen updating and Automatic calculation
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited with BDra correction

Try this code:

```
For i = 10 To 1 Step -1
    If Rows(i).Hidden Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

Change 10 to your number of rows to check. Note that the least index to Rows() is 1, not 0.

Comment: Good answer, except that the loop should run in reverse: `For i = 10 To 1 Step -1`. Otherwise you will inadvertently skip one row every time you delete a row.

Comment: Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52637747/6706419) to see a better way to delete rows while looping

Comment: @urdearboy: Thank you, very useful post, gave it an upvote.

Comment: Thanks all, I figured out a faster way to do this without looping.  I added the code I used above, marked an accepted green check mark.