# Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch Post Office Update

Tags: excel, vba

I previously created code to clean out a spreadsheet. It worked perfectly but it seems that O365 updated and the code broke.

I am still recuperating from COVID and I am having a hard time reading this as my vision was imapcted permanenetly. Could anyone help me understand why it's breaking and where I went wrong? I've

I have not updated this code in over a year and was the last time I wrote a VBS script so I am a bit lost at the moment.

The code breaks at **If rngCell.Value > "" Then** and is the **422* line

Currently trying to find if there's a way for it to provide a better detailed error when it crashes for easier troubleshooting in the future.

```
Dim i As Long


For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "J") <> "Yes" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "K") <> "Yes" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "O") <> "Headquarters" And Cells(i, "O") <> "4205" And Cells(i, "O") <> "2151" And Cells(i, "O") <> "3446" And Cells(i, "O") <> "205" And Cells(i, "O") <> "233" And Cells(i, "O") <> "2182" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i

Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete

Range("C:F" & LastRow).Replace "", "999", xlWhole

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "C").Value2 > 10 And Cells(i, "D").Value2 > 10 And Cells(i, "E").Value2 > 10 And Cells(i, "F").Value2 > 10 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i



ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"

Range("G1").Value = "Queue Name"
Range("G2").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G3").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B3,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G4").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B4,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G5").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B5,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G6").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B6,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G7").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B7,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G8").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B8,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G9").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B9,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G10").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B10,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G11").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B11,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G12").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B12,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G13").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B13,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G14").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B14,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G15").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B15,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G16").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B16,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G17").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B17,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G18").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B18,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G19").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B19,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G20").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B20,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G21").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B21,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G22").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B22,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G23").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B23,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G24").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B24,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G25").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B25,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G26").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B26,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G27").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B27,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G28").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B28,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G29").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B29,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"
Range("G30").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B30,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,7,0)"


Range("H1").Value = "Location"
Range("H2").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B2,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H3").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B3,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H4").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B4,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H5").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B5,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H6").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B6,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H7").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B7,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H8").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B8,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H9").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B9,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H10").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B10,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H11").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B11,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H12").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B12,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H13").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B13,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H14").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B14,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H15").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B15,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H16").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B16,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H17").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B17,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H18").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B18,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H19").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B19,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H20").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B20,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H21").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B21,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H22").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B22,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H23").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B23,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H24").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B24,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H25").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B25,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H26").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B26,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H27").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B27,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H28").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B28,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H29").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B29,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"
Range("H30").Value = "=VLOOKUP(B30,'\\server\server\server\server\[placement.xlsx]Printers'!$A$1:$N$230,5,0)"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("H2:H130" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:O130")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
   End With


    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range

        FindString = "TYS"

        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H:H")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate
                ActiveCell.Value = "TYSONS (9TH FLOOR)"
                Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 7)).Select
                With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
       Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Model"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Serial Number"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Black"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Cyan"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Magenta"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Yellow"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Queue Name"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Else
            End If
        End With


        FindString = "SPF"

        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H:H")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
           If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate
                ActiveCell.Value = "SPF"
                Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 7)).Select
                With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Model"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Serial Number"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Black"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Cyan"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Magenta"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Yellow"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Queue Name"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Else
            End If
        End With

    FindString = "WFR"

        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H:H")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate
                ActiveCell.Value = "WHARF"
                Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 7)).Select
                With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
          Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Model"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Serial Number"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Black"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Cyan"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Magenta"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Yellow"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Queue Name"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Else
           End If
        End With

  FindString = "TES"

        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H:H")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Activate
                ActiveCell.Value = "TYSONS (WGES)"
                Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 7)).Select
                With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Model"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Serial Number"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Black"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Cyan"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Magenta"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Yellow"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = "Queue Name"
    ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Else
            End If
        End With
        

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lngLstCol As Long, lngLstRow As Long

lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lngLstCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Dim rngCell As Variant
For Each rngCell In Range("A1:G100" & lngLstRow)
    If rngCell.Value > "" Then
        r = rngCell.Row
        c = rngCell.Column
        Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, lngLstCol)).Select
            With Selection.Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
   End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete

Range("C:F" & LastRow).Replace "", "999", xlWhole
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "C").Value2 <= 10 Then
    Cells(i, "C").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "D").Value2 <= 10 Then
    Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    End If
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "E").Value2 <= 10 Then
    Cells(i, "E").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next i

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "F").Value2 <= 10 Then
   Cells(i, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next i


Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Range("C:F" & LastRow).Replace "999", "", xlWhole

Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
Rows(1).Delete
Rows(1).Delete
Range("H1").Select

ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Deleting rows inside the loop is extremely inefficient FYI. You are better of filtering and deleting or looping while adding data to a `Union` and then deleting all at once. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637695/vba-deleting-rows-with-the-like-operator/52637747#52637747) is an example of that

Comment: Also, I would recommend compartmentalizing your code such that one sub handles a specific task. Maybe one to do the deleting and another to drop in the VLOOKUPs etc.

Comment: How has no one pointed out that this code isn't [tag:vbscript]? You don't have `As Long` and `As String` this is [tag:vba] syntax.

Answer (score 0):

### Referring to the code snippet below:

1. `Dim rngCell as Range` - not Variant
2. Usually a last row operator goes something like `Range("A1:G" & lr)`. Are you sure you didn't mean that? You are adding the last row to the end of `G100` so if your last row is 5 your loop will go to `G1005`. Unsure if this is intentional
3. You are checking if the value is bigger then a blank cell which doens't make sense. Are you checking if a number is larger than some number? If so, `""` is not a number. Are you checking if the cell is empty? If so `If rng.Cell = ""` would work

---

```
Dim rngCell As Variant
For Each rngCell In Range("A1:G100" & lngLstRow)
    If rngCell.Value > "" Then
```

Comment: You are correct about the Range.

You are also correct about setting the range and have corrected it.

If the cell is blank in general, I wanted it to skip it and go to the next and then proceed. I made a couple of changes based on your answer and IT WORKED!

Dim rngCell As Range
For Each rngCell In Range("A1:G" & lngLstRow)
    If rngCell.Value = vbNullString Then
    Else
   End If
Next

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, v

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lngLstCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Dim rngCell As Variant
For Each rngCell In ws.Range("A1:G" & lngLstRow)
    v = rngCell.Value
    If Not IsError(v) then
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            With ws.Range(c, ws.Cells(c.Row, lngLstCol)).Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If 'not empty
   End If 'not error
Next
```