# Best way to count number of rows after filtering?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to manipulate and copy paste a bunch filtered data and I need the last row of the data after filtering. My dataset is quite large (65000 rows total) so I don't want to use any for loops since that will take too long / crash. What would be the best way to find the last row index (aka length) of a filtered data set then?

Comment: `SpecialCells xlCellTypeVisible` may be of interest. What are you trying to actually do? Finding the last visible row may not be necessary depending on use case (*ex: are you just trying to copy the data? If so, no need to find the last row, just copy the visible cells*)

Comment: I am filtering and hiding certain columns in the data and then copying the data from a series of sheets and pasting them into a single sheet one after the other via a loop

Comment: Heard - so you don't need to know the last visible row. Just copy the entire range and specify to only grab the visible cells.

Comment: How would I copy the entire range when I don't know the size after I filter the data? I don't want any blanks since that will affect my data so I don't want to just do  Range("A1:T65000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Comment: Determine the size of the range before you filter i.e. what is the size of the raw data?. Then filter the data per your criteria. Then copy the entire range with the special cells argument. This will only copy the resultant data of your filter. It's recreating the steps that you would take if you were to manually do this

Comment: [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641756/6706419). In this solution the user wants to delete all the rows that apply to the filter. So you just need to provide your starting range, update the filter to fit your criteria, and change that to copy instead of delete...

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding your data, i.e. layout, what column you filter on & what value(s) do you use to filter, copy from which sheet to which sheet etc. A screenshot would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Something  like this.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()
'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Ctrl + Shift + End
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

The variable named 'LastRow' should have the value that you want.

See more info here.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

**Copy Filtered Ranges – you don’t need `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`**

Time and again on this site I’ve seen questions relating to copying (or deleting) filtered ranges where  the advice invariably includes the need to use the `CellTypeVisible` method.  This advice can come from some of the most respected and reputable SO users.  Contrary to popular belief, this method simply isn’t necessary.

It follows that, if you don’t need to explicitly define the cell type *within* a range to achieve your goal, you also don’t need to waste code defining the range explicitly in the first place by finding last row/column.

**Proof**

Consider the following simple data structure, let’s say it’s on `Sheet1` and you want to filter column `A` to `1` and copy the result to `Sheet2`.

[image: Sample Data]

Try the following code – which doesn’t use the `CellTypeVisible` method:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyNoSpecial()
    With Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter 1, 1        'Filter for the number 1 in Column A
        .Copy Sheet2.Cells(1)   ' Copy - no need to select 'visible cells'
    End With
End Sub
```

Even when you explicitly define the range – you get exactly the same result:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyNoSpecial()
    With Sheet1. Range(“A1:C7”)
        .AutoFilter 1, 1        'Filter for the number 1 in Column A
        .Copy Sheet2.Cells(1)   ' Copy - no need to select 'visible cells'
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to exclude headers, you can use:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyNoSpecial()
        With Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter 1, 2        'Filter for the number 2 in Column A
        .Offset(1).Copy Sheet2.Cells(2, 1) ' option to exclude headers
    End With
End Sub
```

To exclude both the headers and the row below the range, use:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyNoSpecial()
        With Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter 1, 2                'Filter for the number 2 in Column A
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Sheet2.Cells(2, 1) ' excludes headers & row below range
    End With
End Sub
```

Even if you only want to copy part of the filtered range, you simply set the range of interest at the start, such as copying from columns `A` and `B` only. **This is the only time where it may be necessary to carefully define the range prior to applying the filter.**

```
Option Explicit  
Sub CopyNoSpecial()
    With Sheet1.Range("A1:B7")  'Define the range of interest
        .AutoFilter 1, 2                        'Filter for the number 2 in Column A
        .Offset(1).Copy Sheet2.Cells(2, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, as a believer in less-is-more, here’s a simple code to filter a sheet in one line, using the example data filtering column `A` for the number `2`:

`Sheet1.Columns(1).AutoFilter 1, 2`

There’s no need to find the last column, or the last row – the filter applies across the full width and height of the sheet in any case.

If you want to read more, you can find an excellent resource [Here](https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Autofilter_en.html)